# Do we need to merge or close Q's on how to install league of legends?

Tags: discussion

There are a lot of Q/A's on how to Install League Of Legends, most are outdated. I wrote an Article:[League of Legends under Ubuntu](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/league-of-legends-under-ubuntu), i can post it on AU, but are `how to install lol` Q's on-topic here. If so i gladly post it here, as it's proven to be most affective on Older and latest Ubuntu versions.

> Do we need to merge or close Q's on how to install league of legends?

**League Of Legends Q/A**:

- [Install League of Legends on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/381889/36315)
- [Can I play League of Legends in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243434/can-i-play-league-of-legends-in-ubuntu?rq=1)
- [League of Legends on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426763/league-of-legends-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts?rq=1)
- [How to install League Of Legends?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504340/how-to-install-league-of-legends?rq=1)

There are much more, where that came from. I voted to delete, some and commented

`On how to install lol, follow this: [League of Legends under Ubuntu - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/league-of-legends-under-ubuntu) All bug related issues should be asked on the lol Pol page [League Of Legends - Supported software - PlayOnLinux - Run your Windows applications on Linux easily!](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-1135-League_Of_Legends.html)`

Comment: N.B. [the how-to-install LoL](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/league-of-legends-under-ubuntu) post is a bit outdated, as it is for 13.04, and refers to a [source list for precise](http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_precise.list). It could also refer to [How to install Wine](http://askubuntu.com/q/316025/178596) and [How to update PlayonLinux](http://askubuntu.com/q/28801/178596) (which needs updating). Anyway, probably the best thing to with those questions is to pick the best one, and mark all the others as duplicates of them. Merging is probably also a valid option.

Comment: @Wilf  Thats my(homemade) site. I haven't had time to update it(Am currently working on my CMS.). But, it works for Ubuntu 14.04. and any version POL supports.

Comment: @Wilf there was one Q/A, that suggested POL. But, that was a dupe to another older Q/A.